# Drawing State Diagrams

Tags: state-machines

So I'm going through my textbook and I'm stuck on this problem:

- Design a circuit that has two inputs, \$clk\$ and \$X\$, and produces one output \$O\$.

  - \$X\$ may change every clock cycle, and the change happens at the falling edge.
  - The circuit samples the input at every rising edge of the clock.
  - If the input is \$1\$, consider as read a \$1\$, else read a \$0\$. \$O\$ is \$1\$ (for one clock cycle, from positive edge to positive edge) if the last three bits read are \$110\$, with \$0\$ as the most recent bit.

Draw the state diagram. Close to an arc, show \$X=1\$ or \$X=0\$ to indicate whether the change of state happens when \$X=1\$ or when \$X=0\$.

How would one approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First design the state machine without worrying about the clk.  You have to remember something about what happened with the last 3 inputs, so at worst you are going to need 8(=2^3) states (but you can do substantially better than that.)

Once you have the state diagram, you need to choose an n-bit representation for each state.  You will store this in an n bit register.

Then you write down the truth table for the transition function.  There will be n+1 inputs (the n-bit state, and the 1 bit for X.)  There will be n output bits (representing next state.)

Then you figure out how to implement a circuit that performs the truth table.

Finally, you need to implement the output function.  This will be a circuit that is true when you are in the state where the last three bits are 110, and false otherwise.

In your final circuit you will have an n-bit clocked register, and a bunch of combinational logic.

Comment: This helps. Could you also point me towards some examples?

Comment: Here's a classic traffic light controller: http://www.jland.org/swat/e15/lab5/.  The wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine has some very simple examples.

Comment: here's another: http://csclab.murraystate.edu/bob.pilgrim/405/Computing%20Machinery%20Ch04.pdf (pages 93 and 95).